# Show that if $a, b$, and $c$ are integers with $(a,b)=(a,c)=1$, then $(a,bc)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

> Show that if $a, b$, and $c$ are integers with $(a,b)=(a,c)=1$, then
>   $(a,bc)=1$

I don't know exactly that I should use the division algorithm
or $(a,b)=d$, $(a/d,b/d)=1$.

This is my first time to study number theory...
it's very hard...T^T I can't understand basic thms in this study...

Answer (score 1):

Assume $(a,bc)=d>1$. Then $d$ divides $a$ and $bc$. If $p$ is a prime divisor of $d$ then $p$ divides $a$ and $bc$, hence it divides $b$ or $c$ (definition of being prime). This is absurd because $p$ would divide either $(a,b)$ or $(a,c)$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $p$ is a prime number such that $p|(a,bc)$. Then
$$p|a\text{ and }p|bc$$
Since $p$ is a prime number, by [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) $p|b$ or $p|c$ (or both). But if $p|b$, then $(a,b)\geq p$, contradiction. The same applies for $c$. Thus, $(a,bc)=1$.